# YouTrack doesn't work with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to run YouTrack instance with following command:

```
java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.security.egd=/dev/zrandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djetbrains.youtrack.baseUrl=http://localhost/yt -Djetbrains.youtrack.disableBrowser=true -jar /opt/youtrack.jar 3579
```

And i have a nginx proxy (unrelated nginx config parts are omitted):

```
upstream youtrack {
    server localhost:3579;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
            root /var/www/main;
            index index.html;
    }

    location /yt {
            rewrite /yt(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://youtrack;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Every time when i enter url `http://localhost/yt` i'm being redirected to `http://localhost/rootGo` by YouTrack and then obviously get 404 error. Why is this happening and how can one get YouTrack working on sub url?

Answer (score 0):

Try add the /yt contextPath to youtrack.

```
java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.security.egd=/dev/zrandom -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djetbrains.youtrack.baseUrl=http://localhost/yt -Djetbrains.youtrack.disableBrowser=true -jar /opt/youtrack.jar 3579/yt
```

From youtrack documentation:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Installing+YouTrack+with+JAR+Distribution

Starting with YouTrack 6.0.12223 you can run YouTrack Standalone with the following command:

```
java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.awt.headless=true <Optional Java Start Parameters> -jar youtrack-<version>.jar [host:]<port>[/contextPath] [config file path]
```

Implementing support for the 'contextPath' actually allows you now to run YouTrack with the context other then root path previously used by default. Here are a few command examples with various URI configuration for YouTrack server:

```
java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar youtrack-6.0.12124.jar 8080
java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar youtrack-6.0.12124.jar 8080/youtrack
java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar youtrack-6.0.12124.jar 127.0.0.1:8080
java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar youtrack-6.0.12124.jar 127.0.0.1:8080/youtrack
```